# What is the minemum percentage in Metaphone3 that I can use it to tell these names are matched

Tags: java, large-language-model, metaphone

I am working or matching name project, and I am using metaphone3 in java to check if two names are matched phonetically or not, metaphone3 is working great in English names but the names that I am using are Arabic names, so some times i give it two alternative spelling names that should matched but it gives me a low percent, for example Muhammed and Mhmad after calculate the ratio distance between two these names using Fuzzy it gives me they are matched 73.0 !!
and I give it Muhammed and Mahmood, it gives me 83.0 !!

so I am trying to put the percentage let's say if it greater than x then they are matched otherwise they are not, what is the better approach or better way to boost its accurate with non English names
this is my code

```
private boolean metaphone3Ratio(String nameOne, String nameTwo){
        Metaphone3 metaphone3 = new Metaphone3();

        metaphone3.SetEncodeExact(false);
        metaphone3.SetEncodeVowels(true);

        metaphone3.SetWord(nameOne);
        metaphone3.Encode();

        String nameOneEncoded = metaphone3.GetMetaph();

        metaphone3.SetWord(nameTwo);
        metaphone3.Encode();

        String nameTwoEncoded = metaphone3.GetMetaph();

        return FuzzySearch.ratio(nameOneEncoded,nameTwoEncoded) > 88.0;
    }
```